# Selenium и вложенные html-страницы

Tags: java, html, python, selenium-webdriver

Дело было вечером, делать было нечего

Решила попрактиковать свои знания Selenium, а в качестве жертвы взяла игру от Google по сериалу "Doctor Who", приуроченную к 50-летию сериала. https://www.google.com/doodles/doctor-whos-50th-anniversary
Проблема возникла почти сразу же) 
На самой странице пыталась получить доступ ко второму тегу canvas по xPath: `"//div[@id='hplogo']/canvas[2]"`, который выкинул меня в NoSuchElementException. Когда просто вбила `$x("//canvas")`, поняла, что не так всё просто: сама игра представляет собой отдельный HTML документ.

[image]

Так вот, как я могу работать с игрой, оставаясь на этой странице? Как получить доступ к этому документу через основной средствами Selenium? Буду рада любым материалам/ответам на эту тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переключиться на `<iframe>`, в котором находится нужный вам элемент. Это можно сделать с помощью [`switch_to`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to)

Пример на Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.google.com/doodles/doctor-whos-50th-anniversary'
driver.get(url)

# Ищем iframe и переключаемся на него
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('hplogo-complex')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hplogo"]/canvas[2]')
print(canvas)

# Для переключения обратно
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```